How does $1\cdot 2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(n+1)+(i+2)$ become $(i + 2) \cdot(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(i+1)\cdot(i+3)\cdots(n+1)+1)$?
In this equation from a book:
$$\begin{align}
x+i &= 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(n+1) +(i+2) \\
& = (i + 2) \cdot \left(\;1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdots(i+1)\cdot(i+3)\cdots(n+1)+1\;\right)
\end{align}$$
How does this:
$$1\cdot 2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots(n+1)+(i+2)$$
become this?
$$(i + 2) \cdot(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(i+1)\cdot(i+3)\cdots(n+1)+1)$$
Can someone tell me what happened to $4$, and where the $+1$ at the end came from, as well as where the $(i+1)\cdot(i+3)$ came from?
Explain this to me as if I were a child. Thank you.

$abcdefgh+e=e(abcdfgh+1)$

As to what happened to the four, at first they said $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots $ but then they changed it to $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \ldots $ just to save room. The $\ldots $ here means et cetera. "1,2,3,4, et cetra..." is the same thing as "1,2,3, et cetera..."
For the rest, let's use an example, let's say that $n=9$ and $i=5$. So the first line, $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1) \cdot (i+2)$, written out fully is
$$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9\cdot 10 + 7$$
What we want to do now is factor out the $7$.
$$7\cdot(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdot 9\cdot 10 + 1)$$
This is simple. The harder part and the part that is confusing you is how many times you have to use $\ldots$ to write it if you go back to $i$s and $n$s
$$(i + 2) \cdot (1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdot\ldots\cdot(i+1)\cdot(i+3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+1)+1)$$
The point of the $(i+1)\cdot(i+3)$ in the middle there is just to show you that the $i+2$ factor is missing.
